# java How to create a .txt in a directory with the same name

Tags: java, directory

so i need to create a dir and create a txt file inside the dir with the same name..
lets say that my class name is "Mike"

need to make the following

->Mike (Directory)

---->Mike.txt

here is my code:

```
 //variable className is the name of the current class

//create directory using the name of the class
File Dirfile = new File("F:\\"+ className );
Dirfile.mkdir();

//create the .txt inside the dir using the name of the class
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("F:\\" + Dirfile + className + ".txt", true);//<-- this code is not correct.. but i need something like this i mentioned before
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw);
```

Comment: FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(Dirfile.getAbsolutePath() + "\\" + className + ".txt", true);

Comment: @Raghav legend <3

Answer (score 1):

You can try with the following code if `FileWriter` is not a necessary condition.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Test1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String className = "Mike";
    File Dirfile = new File("F:\\" + className + File.separator + className + ".txt");
    Dirfile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    Dirfile.createNewFile();
    Path path = Paths.get(Dirfile.getAbsolutePath());
    Files.write(path, "some test content...".getBytes());
  }
}
```